# How to use LINQ for standard C# application with local database file?

Tags: c#, database, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm used to work with ASP.NET and I have no problems there, but now I need to create a C# Console application and something is wrong.

- I create console application
- Add new item to project (Local database)
- Fill in some basic data (id, name)

But when I create LINQ to SQL Class and drag my table to it like I do in ASP.NET I get error

```
The selected objects use an unsupported data provider
```

What am I doing wrong here, how can I make my work with databases using C# Console/Windows application as fast and easy as with ASP.NET applications?

Comment: How are you connecting to your database?  Where is your connection string defined? Visual Studio will create a web.config file for  ASP.NET applications.  You will need to add an app.config file or hard code the connection string someplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database driver / provider needs to allow for the usage of linq. If you are using a simple sqlite db, I would recommend using the [DBLinq provider](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/).

If you are using Microsoft's lightweight database (Sql Compact) then I believe [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/Compact_LINQ.aspx) maybe helpful.

Comment: Is the SqlMetal goes by default with Visual Studio 2010 installation and I won't have problems using it on different computer that has same compiler installed as me?

Comment: I believe sqlmetal is part of the windows sdk ... I think it gets installed by default with VS 2010. If it's missing you can download the sdk here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx) or add the feature with the VS2010 installer.

Answer (score 0):

The Object Relational Designer (O/R Designer) supports only the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server ( System.Data.SqlClient).

Where as sdf local DB is a Compact Database. SQL Server Compact Edition (System.Data.SqlServerCe) is not supported by O/R Designer.

Instead you can create a db in SQLExpress and connect to Designer